# SQL - Obtain all invoices of people that once had an invoice over $100

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

So I've got a basic SQL question that I can't seem to work out. The query is:
"Obtain all the invoices of customers who have ever had an invoice over $100".

Here's the SQL fiddle I've been using: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/99169/22

The things I've been trying is like:

```
SELECT * from Invoice I 
INNER JOIN Customer C ON C.id=I.customer where I.inv_total > 100.00;
```

But it's not working... any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or sqlite, or both?

Comment: Check out GROUP BY, SUM and perhaps HAVING.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such query:

```
SELECT * from Invoice I 
INNER JOIN Customer C ON C.id=I.customer 
WHERE C.id IN (SELECT customer from Invoice WHERE inv_total > 100)
```

In your where condition you filter customers by invoices that are over 100.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much. Can't accept the answer for 10 mins, but it's yours :)